# Doubts in school code, need some guide

Tags: c

How can I add a while or a jmp(assembly) in this code, if the user doesn't type one of the three options?

```
char tipo[20];
char Equ[] = "equilatero";
char Ret[] = "retangulo";
char Iso[] = "isoceles";
int l,b,h;

printf("digite o tipo de triangulo desejado:\n equilatero ou retangulo/isoceles\n");
scanf("%19s", tipo);
if (strcmp (tipo,Equ) == 0){
    printf("digite o valor do lado \n");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    TriaEqui(l);
}else if (strcmp (tipo,Ret) == 0){
    printf("digite a base");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("digite a altura");
    scanf("%d",&h);
    TriaIsoc(b,h);      
}else if(strcmp (tipo,Iso) == 0){
    printf("digite a base");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("digite a altura");
    scanf("%d",&h);
    TriaIsoc(b,h);      
}else {
    printf("escolha uma das 3 opcoes!");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to edit the code to be in English?

Comment: it's just the 3 areas of triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to change your code much, as effectively all you really need to do is wrap this up in a loop, and break out of the loop if it's one of the required options.

```
char tipo[20];
char Equ[] = "equilatero";
char Ret[] = "retangulo";
char Iso[] = "isoceles";
int l,b,h;

while (1) {
    printf("digite o tipo de triangulo desejado:\n equilatero ou retangulo/isoceles\n");
    scanf("%19s", tipo);
    if (strcmp (tipo,Equ) == 0){
        printf("digite o valor do lado \n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        TriaEqui(l);
        break;
    }else if (strcmp (tipo,Ret) == 0){
        printf("digite a base");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("digite a altura");
        scanf("%d",&h);
        TriaIsoc(b,h);
        break;      
    }else if(strcmp (tipo,Iso) == 0){
        printf("digite a base");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("digite a altura");
        scanf("%d",&h);
        TriaIsoc(b,h);
        break;      
    }else {
        printf("escolha uma das 3 opcoes!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you <3 that worked exactly as i expected.
didn't knew I can use while(1)... kinda new into programming.

Comment: You're welcome :) Any non-zero value is treated as true in C. Sometimes you'll see others use for (;;) instead of while (1) as another infinite loop, as the character 1 can sometimes be confused with the letter l.